# Я поместил в список прямоугольные области. Есть ещё 1 прямоугольная область это персонаж. Как проверить, касается ли персонаж к какой-то из них

Tags: python, pygame, обработка-ошибок

```
hitbox_player = Картинка.get_rect(topleft=(player_x, player_y))

my_list = []

hitbox1 = Картинка.get_rect(topleft=(1230, 300))
hitbox2 = Картинка.get_rect(topleft=(1230, 450))
hitbox3 = Картинка.get_rect(topleft=(1230, 250))

my_list.append(hitbox1, hitbox2, hitbox3)

if hitbox_player.colliderect(my_list):
    main_screen = False
    pygame.quit()
```